# Android Studio can't find class during runtime

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a strange problem where i have included a class in my project, everything builds, but when it runs it crashes saying it cant find the class.

Im using the SlidingUpPanelLayout

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Here is the crash:

```
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.ns.app-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.ns.app-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288) 
         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
         at com.example.ns.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:92) 
         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 
         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2227)
```

Here is the gradle:

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
  compileSdkVersion 24
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
  dexOptions {
      javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
  }
  defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.example.ns.app"
      minSdkVersion 16
      targetSdkVersion 24
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
      testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
multiDexEnabled true
  }
  buildTypes {
      release {
    minifyEnabled false
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
  }

  packagingOptions {
      exclude 'META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.xml'
      exclude 'META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.properties'
  }
  configurations.all {
      resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
          substitute module('org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2') with       module('commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2')
      }
      }
  }



  dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',       {
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  })
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.github.amigold.fundapter:library:1.0'
  compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.6.4'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
  compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.1'
  compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
  }
```

Comment: Try cleaning-rebuilding your project. Also try to make the android support library version, targetSdkVersion and buidToolsVersion of same API level.

Comment: I cleaned it about a thousand times and same problem, maybe it has something to do with this stupid dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader

Comment: Android programming is such a freeking nightmare. I know they are making self-driving cars, im sure anybody who drives in that thing will die for sure if this is how google develop software.

Comment: U added the dependency as a jar?

Comment: No i didnt add it as a jar, but it runs in the emulator and doesnt crash, so why it cant find the class when its run on a real phone?

Comment: How do i add the dependency as a jar? I dont have a jar file, the website instructions said to paste the compile line in the gradle thats what did, and it runs in emulator, but not on the phone. How do i add it as a jar?

Answer (score 0):

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ignite.a01hw909350.kolamdemo"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
        }
    }
```

Add the `abiFilters` in your `build.gradle` app module. Sync and clean your project

Comment: sagar, thanks, i tried it, but it still crashed when i run it on the phone, but the same thing runs on the emulator without crashing. But i noticed the emulator log shows this warning " ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.ns.app-2/lib/x86" I dont know what app-2 is, this maybe the bug. Any more ideas????

Comment: Even I face this problem sometimes. The above solution work sometimes. But if it is not working then we both are sailing in the same boat.

Comment: i hate android programming, its the biggest freeking nightmare i ever seen, everything is so convoluted and they have  a million versions of everything, only god knows which version works with which. Android studio is also a big nightmare, cant believe a company with so much money can make such shitty products!!!

Comment: exactly. You can never be sure that your code will run in all different devices running Android.

Comment: its like they just throw code out there and tell us to take it or leave it or just drop dead, you got no choice because we got all the money and power and  you got nothing, so ha ha!